# Docker cannot start cause of object not found

Tags: database, docker, containers, volumes, mounted-volumes

Today I restarted my PC for an update (Docker was running but I had nothing started or anythingelse) and after the Restart I got greated with the error "Unable to create: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on computer 'C11-CLNFRUBHDWH' because the object was not found. The object might have been deleted. Verify that the Virtual Machine Managment service on the computer is running."

One of the solution said that hyper-V Virtual Machine Managment might not be started, but it is [image]
So the next step is to Uninstall and Reinstall Docker, What scares me is that by doing that all my volumes and containers will be deleted
My docker version is 17.03.1-ce-rc1